# How to reduce labels quantity in barplot R function?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have data frame of dependancies consisted of two columns like this:

```
450    1
1023    2
650    3
...
1200    6501
560    6502
```

So the second column is a continous sequence of integers from 1 to 6512.
I use barplot R function to plot this table of dependancies. My code is:

```
barplot (mir3_21_minus_new$V1,name=mir2_21_minus_new[,2],cex.names=0.8)
```

But I want that the labels on the horizontal axe go after equal strictly determined intervals. For example:
1, 500,1000,1500,2000...5500,6000,6500.
How i can manage this in R (preferable in R standard library)?
Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `hist()` not `barplot()`.  Look at the differences in the following:

```
barplot(mtcars$mpg)
hist(mtcars$mpg)
hist(mtcars$mpg, breaks = seq(0, 40, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, i'm sure that i need  barplot now. hist() will provide me also valuable but another kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

For **barplot()** you may use **axis()**

There are 2 options you may use is below.

**First:**

```
barplot(data$V1)
at = data$V2 %in% c(1,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3500,4000,4500,5000,5500,6000,6500)
axis(side=1, data$V2[at] )
```

In this option first we filter data and filter the values already know. (Not so useful in my opinion)

**Second:**

```
barplot(data$V1)
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,6500,by=500) )
```

In this option just create a sequence with start, end points and increment value.

**Note:** I can not currently try it but if data (6500 data points a bit large for a bar graph) did not fit graph, maybe you should try other graph possibilities.

Comment: Thank You. It works nice, but the problem that the latest label located approximately on the middle of my barplot (I'm sure that latest label in vector must be under the end point of my barplot). So the labels are wrong in this case. Is it possible make some harmonisation of the barplot and labels vector to get correct data representation.

Comment: I have improved my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Probably i indeed should look for another graphical functions in R, cause the barplot don't allow me solve problem with correct labels location on the axis.